# Gson deserialize Array of Integers in kotlin

Tags: list, kotlin, gson, json-deserialization

Normally, when I deserialize a json-String I use something like this:

```
val result = gson.fromJson<myObject>(json, object : TypeToken<myObject>() {}.type)
```

But now I want to deserialize a simple List of Int and I cannot build an object for that.

The json-String is extremely simple and looks like this:

```
[1,35,37,255]
```

and I would like to save it into a List but

```
val result = gson.fromJson<List<Int>>(json, object : TypeToken<List<Int>>() {}.type)
```

does not work because there is no object. How should I handle such an easy structure? Is it better without gson eg with explode?

Comment: "There is no object' Can you put some light over this? The code is valid.

Comment: I am getting proper list of integers with your code.  What problem are you facing ?

Comment: I think that it might have been a problem in another part of the code since I cannot reproduce the problem. With there is no object I meant that in the JSON-code I have no object like {"name":"joe","age":20} but only an array without a name like [1,2,4,8]

Answer (score 1):

I think you in kotlin you don't need to use TypeToken you can go like

```
     val result = gson.fromJson<List<Int>>(json)
```

here if you want to read [more](https://www.kotlinresources.com/library/kotson/#setting-custom-deserializers)

Comment: Thanks, but this did not work (fromJson gets undelinded with the error none of the functions can be called with the argument) - I now used the split-function to make a list

Answer (score 0):

```
val gson = Gson()
val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<Item>>() {}.type
itemList = gson.fromJson<List<Item>>(itemListJsonString, itemType)
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?