# How to deserialize Kotlin array list using Gson?

Tags: java, kotlin

I want to deserialize like this:

```
MyClass myClass = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, MyClass.class);
```

But my object is a kotlin object declared as `val effectsList = arrayListOf<Effect>()`

What should I pass in the place of `MyClass.class`?

Following https://stackoverflow.com/a/57972855/10116440 I tried

```
        val listEffect:List<Effect> = Gson().fromJson(effectsString, List<Effect>.class)
```

but it won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `TypeToken`. Like this:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken


fun main() {
    val gson = Gson()
    val myArrayList = arrayListOf(1, 2, 3)

    val arrayType = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<Int>>() {}.type

    val jsonString = gson.toJson(myArrayList)
    val fromJson: ArrayList<Int> = gson.fromJson(jsonString, arrayType)

    println(fromJson)

}
```